# find match in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to compare two values while having different spelling?

e.g. Column D has the value of "ACTV" and F has the value of "ACTIV". While the spelling of these is different, they have the same meaning and should be matched.

```
D       F
ACTV    ACTIV
```

If the match were exact in spelling, I can use a simple =A1=B1 but in this case, that will not work.

Comment: It's VBA, but look at [Fuzzy Matching](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html)

Comment: may also want to consider the add-in developed by Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011